# SQL obtaining items ranked by their count(*)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been attempting the following query for a while- not sure how to approach this issue I'm having.

I need to obtain bands that cover the second most styles of music - including all equal bands if there is a tie for second.  For example for the table band_style,

```
Band_id    |  Style
---------------------
1            Rock
2            Pop
1            Punk
3            Classical
1            Metal
2            Rock
4            Pop
4            Rap
```

The returned result should be

```
Band_id   | Num_styles
  2          2
  4          2
```

My initial attempt at a solution:

```
SELECT band_id, COUNT(*) AS num_styles FROM band_style 
GROUP BY band_id HAVING COUNT(*) <
(SELECT MAX(c) FROM
(SELECT COUNT(band_id) AS c
FROM band_style
GROUP BY band_id));
```

So this gives me the count of all the bands with less styles than the maximum.  Now, I'd like to take ALL rows which have the maximum value of this query.  I do not want to use rownum or limit because from what I've experienced this doesn't work too well in the case of ties. I am also wondering if there is a way to wrap this in another MAX function, but I don't really see how.

Any help with this issue would be appreciated- also think this would be useful to know to see if it can be applied to 3rd, 4th highest, etc.

(Using Oracle/SQLPlus)
Assuming this is a large data file and we do not necessarily know what the "second highest count" is.

UPDATE: this almost works- gets all bands with less than max number of styles.  But calling MAX doesn't seem to be working, as the table returned still has all values of NUM except the max..

```
WITH data AS (
SELECT band_id, COUNT(*) AS NUM FROM band_style GROUP BY band_id HAVING COUNT  (*) < 
(SELECT MAX(c) FROM
(SELECT COUNT(band_id) AS c
FROM band_style
GROUP BY band_id)))
SELECT data.band_id, data.NUM FROM data
INNER JOIN ( SELECT band_id m, MAX(NUM) n 
         FROM data GROUP BY band_id
       ) t
   ON t.band_id = data.band_id 
     AND t.NUM = data.NUM;
```

Comment: Are you using Oracle or MySQL?

Comment: You're looking for the `RANK` function, which MySQL does not support.  This query is a real pain in MySQL (but easy in Oracle).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ok turns out its SQL*Plus , I had tried using rank, would you mind explaining how rank might be used in this case?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen please see update above - thanks!

Comment: Tag properly!!!!  If this is Oracle, my put MySQL tag?????

Comment: If I ask you what kind of database you use, and you tell me "SQL*Plus", it's like asking what kind of car you drive and you telling me it's a Sony, because that's the name you see on the dash next to the stereo.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: the answer "SQL\*Plus" is not quite the same as that example, because SQL\*Plus can **only** be used with Oracle. But in general I agree: the number of people who can't distinguish between the SQL client and the actual DBMS is disturbingly high ("Which DBMS are you using? - I use Squirrel").

Answer (score 0):

If you have to stick with mysql, this sql will be much more difficult. But if you could switch to **mariadb** or **oracle** this should work.

```
with data as (
  select 
  band_id, count(*) styles, 
  dense_rank() over (order by count(*) desc) place 
  from 
  table1 group by band_id)
select * from data where place=2
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dc3f6/12

Your friend here is the window function **dense_rank**.

The output is:

```
BAND_ID  STYLES  PLACE
2        2       2
4        2       2
```

And here to avoid some missunderstandings, due to place 2 is here styles 2.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2be32/3

Now the styles count is different from the place id.

```
BAND_ID STYLES  PLACE
4       3       2
```

This illustrates that dense_rank does not know the second highest count value beforehand.

Comment: I got this to run, no problem- however, it returns all bands with styles equal to two.  What if this is a large data file and the user doesn't know what the second highest count is?

Comment: You don't need to know. Dense_rank orders the count values and gives place IDs starting from 1. With place =2 you do not filter by counted styles but by place. It is just coincidence that styles count is 2 as well.

Comment: I slightly edited the example you put in the link just to test it out.  Band 1 now has 4 different styles, band 4 has 3 styles, and Band 2 has 2 styles.  However, upon running the SQL I still get Band 2 as second place, though the result should contain Band 4 as having 3 styles, as the second most. Any idea why this might occur?

Comment: please see the update above and let me know what you think, thanks!

Comment: Had to correct the SQL. I ordered from lowest to highest but it should be descending. I don't see in the example band 1 with four styles.